# How to animate changing histogram in Plots.jl?

Tags: julia

I'm working from the [following example](https://juliaplots.github.io/) and failing miserably

```
# initialize the attractor
n = 1500
dt = 0.02
σ, ρ, β = 10., 28., 8/3
x, y, z = 1., 1., 1.

# initialize a 3D plot with 1 empty series
plt = path3d(1, xlim=(-25,25), ylim=(-25,25), zlim=(0,50),
                xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "z",
                title = "Lorenz Attractor", marker = 1)

# build an animated gif, saving every 10th frame
@gif for i=1:n
    dx = σ*(y - x)     ; x += dt * dx
    dy = x*(ρ - z) - y ; y += dt * dy
    dz = x*y - β*z     ; z += dt * dz
    push!(plt, x, y, z)
end every 10
```

I have simulations in which I want to calculate and plot a histogram every so often, and then animate all those histograms. This is what I have so far as a toy example:

```
using Distributions
using Plots
Plots.gr()

p = rand(Normal(0,1), 10000)
myplot = Plots. histogram(p)
savefig("initial.png")

anim = @animate for i=1:10
    p = rand(Normal(0,1), 10000)
    push!(myplot, Plots.histogram(p))
end

gif(anim, "mygif.gif", fps = 1)
```

As you can probably tell, I don't really get how this @animate thing works and am just guessing at the syntax here. I know that I could save a bunch of PNGs and later animate, but I want to try it this way.

Comment: You're replotting the same histogram over and over - that will not creat an animation. Instead, just call `histogram(rnorm(10000))` inside the loop.

Comment: It's pretty well explained in the documentation https://juliaplots.github.io/animations/ and links therein.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard fixed

Comment: @skleinbo Maybe to you it is

Comment: The correct call within the for loop is `histogram(p)` rather than `push!(myplot, Plots.histogram(p))`. But what is the error you are getting - the imagemagick error? https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/489

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm not getting an error associated with making gifs, for example I can run the Lorenz attractor animated gif example [on this page](https://juliaplots.github.io/) just fine. When I replace `push!(myplot, Plots.histogram(p))` with just `Plots.histogram(p))` above, I do get a gif, but it contains only one image. When I use the `push!` syntax (which I don't really understand but am trying to adapt from the example), I get this error: `ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching push!(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}, ::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend})
`. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard OMG I was using `Plots.histogram()` instead of `histogram()`. It works! I guess the whole `push!` thing was unnecessary. Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear, I've posted an answer. If you have any suggestions for clarifying this in the docs it would be very helpful.

Comment: Sure. I think a minimal example with @gif and/or @animate would be helpful...for my part I did not understand that `push!` and/or `plot!` weren't required based on looking at the Plots home page. I see that that's basically there on https://juliaplots.github.io/animations/ -- maybe just expand `anim = @animate for i=1:100
    plot(...)
end
gif(anim, "/tmp/anim_fps15.gif", fps = 15)` to be a fully working example.  I guess people viewing the docs have very different levels of knowledge, and I'm probably on the low end.... Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
anim = @animate for i=1:10
    p = rand(Normal(0,1), 10000)
    histogram(p)
end

gif(anim, "mygif.gif", fps = 1)
```

should work.

Comment: A followup question if I may. I have a simulation for which I want to construct a histogram every `t` units of time. If I start the main simulation loop with `anim = @animate for i=1:N` (where N is large) and then I try to put the `histogram()` inside of an `if i % 100 == 0` conditional, it doesn't work (`ERROR: LoadError: No current plot/subplot`). I found a workaround which is to do all simulation code and then `continue` if `i % 100` isn't zero, and then put the `histogram()` call after that conditional, but that feels kind of clunky, might you suggest a better way? Thank you.

Comment: I think the best is to append `every 100` to your loop (after `end` on the same line)

Comment: Nice answer. We can do ``anim = @animate ...`` and save it with ``gif(anim, "gif.gif", fps=1)`` . What would be the way to save an animation created by ``@gif``? I tried simply replacing ``@animate`` by ``@gif``, but that  didn't work. Thanks.